# Coordinate conversion without graphing?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Consider the region given by $R= \left\{x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0, x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1\right\}$
>
> By letting $x = r\sin \phi \cos \theta, ~ y= r \sin \phi \sin \theta,
> ~ z= r\cos \phi$, show that
>
> $$R =  \left\{\theta \in [0, \pi/2], \phi \in [0, \pi/2], r \in
>  [0,1]\right\}$$   (No graphing allowed. Determine $\theta, \phi, r$
>   from the parametric equations).

I think I see that $r \cos{\phi} \ge 0 \implies \phi \in [0,\pi/2].$ But sometimes this wouldn't be right because it would also depend on the second equation $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$. I've seen that sometimes $\phi \in [0,\pi/4]$ but letting $r\cos \phi \ge 0$ would always give $\phi \in [0,\pi/2]$. And how do you find $\theta$?

Comment: $\cos \phi \ge 0 \implies \phi \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Comment: @saulspatz I see. How do we get from that to $\phi \in [0, \pi/2]$? Can we find $\theta$ similarly? Is it right to say that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$ has no effect on the range of $\phi, \theta$? As in we didn't consider it when finding $\phi$ (except in the sense that it gives us $r$).

Comment: What restricts the angles is $x\ge0, y\ge0, z\ge0$  As you say, $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$ just gives us $r$.

Comment: @saulspatz You have shown that $\phi \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ where's apparently the answer is $ \phi \in [0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: I was just saying that you were jumping to an unjustified conclusion, and  more work is needed.  If you want to conclude that $\phi\in [0,\pi/2]$ you need to show $\cos \phi\ge 0, \sin\phi\ge 0$

Comment: @saulspatz Oh, my bad. That's the type of analysis I was after. Do you mind say more about that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3: x,y,z\geq 0\land x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\},$ which is the proper way to write it. Let $S=\{(r\sin A\sin B, r\sin A\cos B, r\cos A): r\in [0,1]\land A,B\in [0,\pi /2]\}.$

Show (i) $S\subset R,$ and (ii) $R\subset S.$

(i). If $p=(x,y,z)=(r\sin A\sin B, r\sin A\cos B,r\cos B)=(x,y,z)\in S \;$ with $r\in [0,1]$ and $A,B\in [0,\pi /2]$ then $x,y,z\geq 0$, and by direct calculation $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\leq 1, $ so $p\in R$.

(ii). If $p=(x,y,z)\in R$ let  $r=\sqrt {x^2+y^2+z^2}.$ Then $r\in [0,1].$

There exist $s,t\in [0,1]$ such that $s^2+t^2=1$ and $z=tr$ and $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\;=sr.$  So there exists $B\in [0,\pi /2]$ such that $s=\sin B$ and $t=\cos B.$

There exist $u,v\in [0,1]$ such that $u^2+v^2=1$ and $x=u\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\;$ and $y=v\sqrt {x^2+y^2}.$   So there exists $A\in [0,\pi /2]$ such that $u=\sin A$ and $v=\cos A.$

Then $p=(x,y,z)=(r\sin A\sin B,r\sin A\cos B, r\cos B)\in S.$

Comment: Thanks. This does it! Just out of interest, in the case where $S$ isn't given explicitly, and you're required $R$ in the form of $S$ does this approach work? I'm assuming we have to sort of guess which angles work for the subsets to contain each other.

Comment: CASE 1. If $ r=0$ then  any $A, B$ will do. CASE 2. If  $r\ne 0$ then $z$ and  $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\;$ are not both $0$ so $s$ and $t$ are unique, which uniquely determines $B=\sin^{-1}s .$ CASE 2a.  If $z\ne 0=x=y $ then   $\sin B=B =0$ and any $A$ will do. CASE 2b. If $x,y$ are not both $ 0$ then $u,v$ are unique , which uniquely determines $A=\sin^{-1}u,$ and $B$ is also unique because $r\ne 0. $

Comment: This absolutely fantastic! Thank you very much.  I'm learning so much from this reply and comment!

Comment: Consider, for $r\ne 0,$  the surface of a sphere of radius $r,$ centered at $(0,0,0).$  We may call $\pi /2-B$ the north latitude of $(x,y,z)$  and $A$ the longitude . If $(x,y,z)=(0,0,r)$ is the north pole of the sphere,  $A$  could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos (\phi )\ge 0 \implies 0\le \phi \le \pi/2 $$
but depending on the problem you find the actual range of$ \phi$ which in this case is $$ 0\le \phi \le \pi/2$$

With regards to $\theta $ ,

Since both your $x$ and $y$ are non-negative, you have both $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos (\theta)$ non-negative, thus $0\le \theta \le \pi /2 $

Comment: Why does $\cos (\phi )\ge 0 \implies 0\le \phi \le \pi$? Isn't $\cos \phi $ negative for $\phi \in (\pi/2, \pi)$? And how do you find the actual range of $\phi$ in this case?

Comment: You are correct. I have edited my solution.

Comment: When you say "which in this case is..." I'm not sure where that's coming from. How did you determine that algebraically? I mean yes, $\cos \phi \ge 0 \implies \phi \in [0, \pi/2]$ but if $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1$ was something else and $r=1$, we could have $\cos \phi \ge 0 \implies \phi \in [0, \pi/2]$ but that wouldn't necessarily be the right range for $\phi$.

Comment: Your  $ 0 \le z \le r $ makes   $0 \le  cos(\phi) \le1 $

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, not an answer, but it's too long.  The point is that you can always tell what quadrant an angle lies in by the signs of the sine and cosine.  This is clear from the polar form $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta)$.

In the first quadrant, both functions are positive.
In the third quadrant, both are negative.
In the second quadrant, sine is positive and cosine negative.
In the fourth quadrant, sine is negative and cosine positive.

That is, cosine and sine have the same signs as $x$ and $y$, respectively.